# Is this a correct desugaring of the computation workflow?

Tags: f#, workflow, bind

This is from Expert F# 2.0 page 231. Apparently the following block of code

```
attempt { let! n1 = failIfBig inp1
let! n2 = failIfBig inp2
let sum = n1 + n2
return sum };;
```

de-sugars to this:

```
attempt.Bind( failIfBig inp1,(fun n1 ->
attempt.Bind(failIfBig inp2,(fun n2 ->
attempt.Return sum)))))
```

but where is `sum` computed in the de-sugared variant? I expected something more like this:

```
attempt.Bind( failIfBig inp1,(fun n1 ->
attempt.Bind(failIfBig inp2,(fun n2 -> let sum = n1 +  n2 in
attempt.Return sum)))))
```

Comment: Yes, the translation is exactly as you show in the second snippet. (It would be more complicated if the computation budilder defined `Delay` or `Run`, but I think that's not the case here)

Comment: There are also a few examples of translation in the freely available Chapter 12 of my book: http://manning.com/petricek/SampleChapter12.pdf

Comment: Wrapping computation expressions in Quotations will also help you see how they are desugared. Unquote (http://code.google.com/p/unquote/) can make this even more clear, since at version 1.3.0 at least it doesn't "resugar" them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's an error in the book and it should be de-sugared as below:

```
attempt.Bind( failIfBig inp1,(fun n1 ->
attempt.Bind(failIfBig inp2,(fun n2 -> let sum = n1 +  n2 in
attempt.Return sum)))))
```